How do I get rich text format by py from the clipboard instead of plain text?
How can I retrieve rich text format content from the clipboard in Python after copying it from Excel or HTML?
I tried pyperclip and clipboard python package, but they only output plain text.
I would like Python to directly output rich text formatted content, not just plain text content.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Nobody answers, I will refer to the example code of the clipboard in pywin32 to write it myself.
PYTHON
Refer to link: https://gist.github.com/Erreinion/6691093
import win32clipboard


def GetAvailableFormats():
    """
    Return a possibly empty list of formats available on the clipboard
    """
    formats = []
    try:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard(0)
        cf = win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats(0)
        while (cf != 0):
            formats.append(cf)
            cf = win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats(cf)
    finally:
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

    return formats

# CF_HTML=49433
CF_HTML = win32clipboard.RegisterClipboardFormat("HTML Format")

if CF_HTML in GetAvailableFormats():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard(0)
    src = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(CF_HTML)
    src = src.decode("UTF-8")
    print(src)
else:
    print("No RTF content")

OR
pip install klembord

The author of kembord is not correctly fetching the clipboard. Please modify the html = html.decode(UTF8)[131:-38] line in the get_with_rich_text method of init.py as:
from re import search
html = search("<html>([\\s\\S]+)</html>",html.decode(UTF8)).group(0)

example code:
import klembord
# copy content
klembord.set_with_rich_text('Hello, world!', '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>')
# print content
print(klembord.get_with_rich_text()[1])

